# Using JMX client to connect to the WebSphere JVM

Tags: websphere, jmx

How I can connect to  WebSphere JVM through JMX client? Can JMX client be used to connect to the WebSphere JVM to change logging settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to use some Websphere-specific jars in order to connect to WAS using a JMX Client.
You may follow [this article](http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2012/09/12/configuring-jmx-in-websphere-8-5/) in order to configure this.